# Setting Constraints in viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `uiview` in the center of the `viewcontroller`. There is a `uilabel` above (A) and below (B) this `uiview`.

I want to programmatically change the bottom constraint of this `uiview` so that the distance above and below the `uiview` are equal to each other as screen size changes. So calculating the distance between top `uiview` to bottom of `uilabel` (A) and distance between bottom `uiview` to top of `uilabel` (B), dividing by 2 and then setting the bottom constraint constant accordingly.

I have the calculation done, but it only seems to work when i place it in `viewDidAppear` and i need the constraints and views to be in their right place before the user is able to see the objects. Is this possible to do in `viewWillAppear`. it feels like all the elements are not set until `viewDidAppear` for me to calculate correctly..i believe it has to do with the lifecycle of `autolayout` not completing prior to the calculation..

```
let topDistance = view.frame.minY - ALabel.frame.maxY
    let bottomDistance = BLabel.frame.minY - view.frame.maxY
    let total = topDistance + bottomDistance
    bottomConstraint.constant = total / 2
```

Below is a before/after example of the desired result where the purple `uiview` has a bottom constraint to the bottom orange `uilabel`. when the screen size increases in length, as an example, i want the bottom constraint to have the same constant as the distance between the purple `uiview` and top orange `uilabel`. The top `uilabel` has a top constraint to the top and the bottom `uilabel` has a bottom constraint to the bottom.
[image: Example]

Comment: Please add image for what you want.

Comment: I think that what you want can be set up without calculations, using static constraints only.

Comment: Your description is not quite clear. You have 3 elements: `TopLabel` (**T**), `CenterView` (**CV**), `BottomLabel` (**B**), aligned vertically in `MainView` (**MV**), correct? And you want equal vertical spacing from the top of `MV` to the top of `T`; the bottom of `T` to the top of `CV`; the bottom of `CV` to the top of `B`; and the bottom of `B` to the bottom of `MV`? Is that correct?

Comment: @MayurKarmur i have added a picture and explanation, does this help clarify more?

Comment: @DonMag i have added a picture and explanation, does this help make it more clear?

Comment: @Sulthan im open to hearing how this might be done!

Comment: @Chris - sorry, still just a bit confusing. `TopLabel` is constrained to the top of `MainView`? And `BottomLabel` is constrained to the bottom of `MainView`? If so, then don't constrain Purple to either label... just constrain it centerY

Comment: Exactly, It seems to me the purple one should be vertically centered and the top orange should just get a top constraint to superview and the bottom orange should just get a bottom constraint to superview.

Comment: @DonMag it's a little more complicated then that, i just explained my issue with 3 components to simplify. there are a lot more elements within the viewcontroller itself, but the main idea is that the top and bottom uilabels will move according to its unique constraint and i ultimately need the uiview to be constrained equidistant from the both uilabels. so is there a way to dynamically achieve this equality? my posted code does this but only in viewDidAppear after things have set..i think there's an issue with the lifecycle of autolayout completing for me to then update the uiview constraint

Comment: @Sulthan looping you in to my above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and answer your question:

You're right, that auto-layout has not finished doing its work in `viewDidLoad()` or even `viewWillAppear()`. Generally, when you need to do layout adjustments like that, you want to do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. From Apple's docs:

> **viewDidLayoutSubviews**
>
> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method.

However, if I understand what you're actually trying to do...

By using a `UIStackView` you can avoid needing to use *any* code.

Embed your labels, views, buttons, etc in a Vertical `UIStackView`. Set the properties to:

```
Alignment: Fill   (or Leading or Center as suits your layout)
Distribution: Equal Spacing
Spacing: 0
```

Constrain the stack view's Top to the Top of the view (plus any desired padding) and the Bottom to the Bottom of the view (plus any desired padding).

Result with iPhone SE size:

[image]

Result with iPhone 8 size:

[image]

Result with iPhone XS size:

[image]

And, here's iPhone 8 with a couple additional elements of varying heights:

[image]

As you see, the elements have equal vertical spacing between them, and it's all handled by the stack view.

Comment: stack view won't work again because of i have various components in relation to each other and moving parts in the vc. with that said, it appears placing the code in viewDidLayoutSubviews actually worked in showing the right placement of the element prior displaying to the user!

Answer (score 1):

Write `layoutIfNeeded` after update constraint.

```
let topDistance = view.frame.minY - ALabel.frame.maxY
let bottomDistance = BLabel.frame.minY - view.frame.maxY
let total = topDistance + bottomDistance
bottomConstraint.constant = total / 2
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use View did appear is already when user see the VeiwController, 
Use viewDidLoad instead , u can't use viewWillAppear , because View isn't loaded yet.

Use it on:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

And u can try call

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 1):

When I want to set constraints programmatically I usually proceed like this :

```
let v = UIView()
v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(v)
v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
v.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dispatch Queue for this:

```
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          let topDistance = view.frame.minY - ALabel.frame.maxY
          let bottomDistance = BLabel.frame.minY - view.frame.maxY
          let total = topDistance + bottomDistance
          bottomConstraint.constant = total / 2
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```